# How is module augmentation supposed to compile

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I understand the concept of [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation). I can get things to compile and I'm able to get the functionality I want, except I can't get the types to be detected from my augmentation. This is a simplification of what I've got going on.

I have a class in `src/moviedb.ts`

```
export class MovieDb {
  // Implementation...
}
```

Then in `src/endpoints/index.ts`

```
import { MovieDb } from '../moviedb'
import Configuration from './methods/configuration'
import { RequestParams, RequestOptions } from '../types'

// Eventually there will be a lot of modules here
// They all share the same implementation, 
// only their typings and configuration change
const endpointGroups = [
  Configuration,
]

// Create the dynamic api methods
for (const group of endpointGroups) {
  for (const endpoint of group.endpoints) {
    const method = group.prefix + (endpoint.name || '')

    MovieDb.prototype[method] = async function (params: string|RequestParams = {}, options: RequestOptions = {}) {
      // Implementation...
    }
  }
}
```

Then in `src/endpoints/methods/configuration.ts`

```
import {
  HttpMethod,
  EndpointGroup,
  Response,
  RequestOptions
} from '../../types'

const Configuration: EndpointGroup = {
  prefix: 'configuration',
  endpoints: [
    {
      path: 'configuration',
      verb: HttpMethod.Get
    }
  ]
}

interface ConfigurationResponse extends Response {
  change_keys: Array<string>
  images: {
    base_url?: string
    secure_base_url?: string
    backdrop_sizes?: Array<string>
    logo_sizes?: Array<string>
    poster_sizes?: Array<string>
    profile_sizes?: Array<string>
    still_sizes?: Array<string>
  }
}

// Module augmentation
declare module '../../moviedb' {
  interface MovieDb {
    configuration(options?: RequestOptions): Promise<ConfigurationResponse>
  }
}

export default Configuration
```

When the ts compiles, I'm not sure how the definition files are supposed to look (as in, are the augmentations supposed to be merged with the underlying `MovieDb` class definition?). I can call the `configuration` method on an instance of the `MovieDb` class, but VS Code can't pick the autocompletion/types.

Is it too obfuscated to be detected? I'm newer to Typescript, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

### Update 1

I found that if I move the augmentation into `src/endpoints/index.ts` I get both the functionality and intellisense. I can't explain why, though.

```
import { MovieDb } from '../moviedb'
import Configuration from './methods/configuration'
import { RequestParams, RequestOptions } from '../types'

const endpointGroups = [
  Configuration,
]

// Augmentation moved here and removed from src/endpoints/methods/configuration
interface ConfigurationResponse extends Response {
  change_keys: Array<string>
  images: {
    base_url?: string
    secure_base_url?: string
    backdrop_sizes?: Array<string>
    logo_sizes?: Array<string>
    poster_sizes?: Array<string>
    profile_sizes?: Array<string>
    still_sizes?: Array<string>
  }
}

declare module '../moviedb' {
  interface MovieDb {
    configuration(options?: RequestOptions): Promise<ConfigurationResponse>
  }
}

// Create the dynamic api methods
for (const group of endpointGroups) {
  for (const endpoint of group.endpoints) {
    const method = group.prefix + (endpoint.name || '')

    MovieDb.prototype[method] = async function (params: string|RequestParams = {}, options: RequestOptions = {}) {
      console.log(`calling ${method}`, params)

      return this.makeRequest(endpoint.verb, endpoint.path, params, options)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to augment your own modules?

Comment: @AlekseyL. yes, but I'm leaning towards tackling this problem another way....

Comment: The problem here is with paths. You're using relative path when augmenting the module. Anyway this looks useless (sorry) because there's no reason to augment modules from the same codebase.

Comment: Well then I guess MS has it wrong too, because [their examples in the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) uses relative paths. There are [other examples](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3290-using-module-augmentation-to-safely-inject-runtime-methods-using-typescript-and-node-js.htm) of people using relative paths. I updated my question to show that actually moving the augmentation one directory up works just fine. You clearly didn't read the question and snippets fully for my explanation as to why I am needing it.

Comment: I'm not saying that using relative paths is wrong (it was just guess that it has something to do with project structure). Is this good solution or not is another discussion, but actually your initial snippet works and ide picks the definitions without a problem https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-sanderson-nybe2?file=/src/index.ts